# Which is better in python, del or delattr?

Tags: python, del

This may be silly, but it's been nagging the back of my brain for a while.

Python gives us two built-in ways to delete attributes from objects, the **del** command word and the **delattr** built-in function. I prefer **delattr** because it I think its a bit more explicit:

```
del foo.bar
delattr(foo, "bar")
```

But I'm wondering if there might be under-the-hood differences between them.

Answer (score 334, accepted):

The first is more efficient than the second.  `del foo.bar` compiles to two bytecode instructions:

```
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (foo)
              3 DELETE_ATTR              0 (bar)
```

whereas `delattr(foo, "bar")` takes five:

```
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (delattr)
              3 LOAD_FAST                0 (foo)
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 ('bar')
              9 CALL_FUNCTION            2
             12 POP_TOP
```

This translates into the first running *slightly* faster (but it's not a huge difference – .15 μs on my machine).

Like the others have said, you should really only use the second form when the attribute that you're deleting is determined dynamically.

[Edited to show the bytecode instructions generated inside a function, where the compiler can use `LOAD_FAST` and `LOAD_GLOBAL`]

Comment: What tool did you use to generate this?

Comment: The `dis` module. You can run it from the command line using `python -m dis` and typing in some code, or disassemble a function with `dis.dis()`.

Comment: Premature optimization is the root of all evil. ;-) But yes, you are right, of course.

Comment: ..so does it follow that the love of money is premature optimization?

Comment: @John Fouhy only if you subscribe to both assertions.  But both have stood the test of time.

Comment: Premature optimization is a subset of the love of money, as it means you're trying to spend less on processing power :)

Comment: This isn't premature optimization but rather an empirical approach in making a decision as to which approach is better

Comment: I think it's important to note there are no Python programs where 150 ns will be significant in any way, so the time "efficiency difference" between the two methods should not be the determining factor in which to use. Rather, readability and if you need to pass a string or not should probably be the deciding factor.

Answer (score 50):

- **del** is more explicit and efficient;
- **delattr** allows dynamic attribute deleting.

Consider the following examples:

```
for name in ATTRIBUTES:
    delattr(obj, name)
```

or:

```
def _cleanup(self, name):
    """Do cleanup for an attribute"""
    value = getattr(self, name)
    self._pre_cleanup(name, value)
    delattr(self, name)
    self._post_cleanup(name, value)
```

You can't do it with **del**.

Comment: You can do the second one with del. `del self.__dict__[name]`, assuming of course no funny business going on with the meta class

Answer (score 20):

Unquestionably the former.  In my view this is like asking whether `foo.bar` is better than `getattr(foo, "bar")`, and I don't think anyone is asking that question :)

Comment: I'm sure there's at least *one* person out there that would prefer getattr(foo, "bar") over foo.bar.  Granted, I wouldn't agree with them.  But that one person is still enough to make it not unquestionably the former.

Comment: @Jason Then nothing is "unquestionably better" than anything else by your interpretation of the phrase.  I think this is a perfectly reasonable use of "unquestionably".

Comment: getattr is preferable when there's a possibility that the property does not exist and you wish to set a default value without having to write try/except blocks. 

ie. gettattr(foo, "bar", None)

Comment: @MarcGibbons: Wait, that's a thing? I've always used the pattern `if hasattr(obj, 'var') and obj.var == ...`... I could just reduce this to, `if getattr(obj, 'var', None) == ...` in most cases! Slightly shorter and easier to read, I think.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare `hasattr` actually calls `getattr`

Answer (score 16):

It's really a matter of preference, but the first is probably preferable.  I'd only use the second one if you don't know the name of the attribute that you're deleting ahead of time.

Answer (score 6):

Just like getattr and setattr, delattr should only be used when the attribute name is unknown.

In that sense, it's roughly equivalent to several python features that are used to access built-in functionality at a lower level than you normally have available, such as `__import__` instead of `import` and `operator.add` instead of `+`

Answer (score 3):

Not sure about the inner workings, but from a code reusability and don't be a jerk coworker perspective, use del. It's more clear and understood by people coming from other languages as well.

Answer (score 3):

It is an old question, but I would like to put my 2 cents in.

Though, `del foo.bar` is more elegant, at times you will need `delattr(foo, "bar")`. Say, if you have an interactive command line interface that allows a user to dynamically delete any member in the object by *typing the name*, then you have no choice but to use the latter form.

Answer (score 2):

If you think `delattr` is more explicit, then why not used `getattr` all the time rather than `object.attr`?

As for under the hood... your guess is as good as mine. If not significantly better.