# Delete attribute of a class using its instance

Tags: python

I've a class say `QClass` and an instance `Q` of `QClass`.

I've somehow created an attribute `an_attribute` at run time in `QClass`.
How do I delete that `an_attribute` using `del Q.an_attribute`?

I know that deleting that attribute from class will make it inaccessible from all of its instances.

**Update**: `Q` is exposed to user and they can only go with `del Q.an_attribute`. I can only change code of `Q` or `QClass`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`del` in python is more efficient than `delattr`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/1121068/4698026

So, go with

```
del type(Q).an_attribute
```

Answer (score 2):

try `del type(Q).an_attribute`.

type(Q) will return QClass and then you use del with it.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
delattr(Q, 'an_attribute')
```