# Python AttributeError raised

Tags: python

I experienced an "AttributeError" with the following Python code:

```
Def SomeFunc(Self):
    ....
    setattr(Self, "_Some_Attribute", Data)
    ....
    if hasattr(Self, "_Some_Attribute"):
        delattr(Self, "_Some_Attribute")
    ....
```

And the AttributeError was raise on the delattr line immediately after the hasattr test was positive. The panic was pretty rare. I would say once in few hundreds times.

SomeFunc() may be called from multiple threads.  Is it possible that another thread get in between the hasattr and delattr to remove the "_Some_Attribute" after the first thread test hasattr positive?

Comment: Please post actual code.

Comment: Also, please check for duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120927/which-is-better-in-python-del-or-delattr

Comment: `hasattr` and `delattr` are all lowercase. Voting to close as typo.

Comment: Sorry about the typo.  The actual code is:
                if hasattr(Self, "_Some_Attribute"):
                    delattr(Self, "_Some_Attribute")

Comment: In the other answer you mentioned _" The panic was pretty rare. I would say once in few hundreds times. "_ Is this a multithreaded app? In your real code, is there more processing between the `hasattr` and `delattr` that could have logic errors? As stands, your problem is not reproducable.

Comment: Yes, it is multi-threaded. And definitely no processing in between hasattr and delattr on a single thread.  The code is like that.
Is it possible that another thread get in between the hasattr and delattr to remove the "_Some_Attribute"?  Anyone who know GIL enough to tell if that is possible?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

When looking up an attribute on an object, python first looks at `self` and then at the class namespace. So, instance variables and class variables both pass the `hasattr` test. Such is not the case when deleting attributes. Class variables will not be deleted.

```
class C(object):

    classvar = 'foo'

    def __init__(self):
        self.instancevar = 'bar'

c = C()
print('hasattr sees instance and class vars', hasattr(c, 'classvar'), hasattr(c, 'instancevar'))
print('delete instance is fine')
delattr(c, 'instancevar')
print('but classvar is not')
delattr(c, 'classvar')
```

When run, you get your error

```
hasattr sees instance and class vars True True
delete instance is fine
but classvar is not
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "u.py", line 13, in <module>
    delattr(c, 'classvar')
AttributeError: classvar
```

*EDIT*

With the revised code, I can no longer reproduce. My test case below works without error.

```
class C(object):
    def test(self):
        setattr(self, '_foo', 'bar')
        if hasattr(self, '_foo'):
            delattr(self, '_foo')
C().test()
print("Test Passed")
```

Comment: Thank you.  This is really good to know.  However, I don't that is my case.  Please see the actual code that I posted.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear why the problem occurs in your case. The code snippets you gave are not enough for a conclusive analysis.

However, there is a solution nevertheless!

Instead of:

```
if hasattr(Self, "_Some_Attribute"):
    delattr(Self, "_Some_Attribute")
```

Do this:

```
try:
    delattr(Self, "_Some_Attribute")
except AttributeError:
    # here you choose what you want to do, some options:
    pass
    print 'delattr failed' if hasattr(Self, "_Some_Attribute") else 'ok'
    assert not hasattr(Self, "_Some_Attribute")
```

[It is easier to ask for forgiveness than permission.](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-eafp)