# Object Oriented in Python 3: Attributes

Tags: python

```
class Human:

    pass

stack = Human()
stack.name  #<- means? how to hide or kill or make to unusable **.name** ?
```

Can someone help me? Can I kill such undefined attributes in Object oriented in Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Human():
 pass

m1 = Human()
try:
 m1.name
except AttributeError:
 pass # for hiding this error or you can use (print "this attribute does not exist ")
```

If your intended purpose is deleting an attribute use this methods :

method 1 : use `del`

```
  >>> class Human():

    def __init__(self,name,lastname):
        self.name = name
        self.lastname = lastname


>>> m1 = Human('name' , 'lastname')
```

before deleting

```
>>> m1.name
'name'
>>> del m1.name
```

after deleting

```
>>> m1.name

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#101>", line 1, in <module>
    m1.name
AttributeError: Human instance has no attribute 'name'
```

method 2 :
 you can use `delattr(Human, "name")`

Note 1 : method 1 is better than method 2 for see **why** and more detail click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120927/which-is-better-in-python-del-or-delattr)